# How do I get my cosmetic reward for The B-Win Protocol?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

The quest description said I'd get a hat, and it looks like a unicorn horn hat, from what I remember of the icon. But I can't see it for sale by Calista (Vendor), nor in my Headwear in Customize?

It looks sort of like the Animal Hat, because that's the only hat I see with a horn, but I already had that before I finished the quest.